# How to change the alpha value of an Android button when held programatically?

Tags: android, user-interface, button

I want to make it so when I hold down a button the alpha value decreases.
When I release it it sets the alpha value back to 1 and does an action.
This button has been made programatically.

How would you also check that the release is on top of the button?
Something like this:
`btn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            btn.setAlpha(0.7f);
        }
        else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            btn.setAlpha(0.85f);
            if (btn.isFocused())
            {
                // Do something here
            }
        }
        return true;
    });
}`

Comment: you should try to use the `onTouch` event and then find its is `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` or `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and perform ur operations

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the touch event of the button to perform your operations on it 
Something similar to below

btn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        if (arg1.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
         // your down operations
         //in your case btn.setAlpha() here
        }
        else if (arg1.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
         // your up operations
         //in your case btn.setAlpha() here

        }
   }
}
```

Comment: How would you also check that on release that the user is still over the button?
Edited original post with code.

Comment: check for the touch location and the bounds of the button view. If the location is inside then you know its inside :P